# Why offsetHeight is smaller than clientHeight?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**FACTS:**

`clientHeight`: Returns the height of an element, including padding

`offsetHeight`: Returns the height of an element, including padding, border and scrollbar

**Conclusion:**

`offsetHeight` should return more pixels than `clientHeight`. `offsetHeight` is bigger than `clientHeight`.

**Question:**

When I use these two properties on `HTML` tag, it returns 8 from `offsetHeight` and 778 from `clientHeight`.

Why's that? `offsetHeight` should be bigger than `clientHeight`, shouldn't it?

Then why is it only 8 pixels? What's happening here?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html id = "foo">
    <body>
        <script>
            var element = document.getElementById('foo');

            var osHeight = element.offsetHeight;
            var cHeight = element.clientHeight;

            document.write("Offset Height is " + osHeight + "<br/>");
            document.write("Client Height is " + cHeight);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
Offset Height is 8
Client Height is 778
```

Comment: It's because you're partially wrong, and because you're checking the `html` element. There is nothing taking up space in the document, and you haven't set a height, so the height is really just 8 pixels, like `offsetHeight` returns, but `clientHeight` is returning the visible height of the document, which is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the client height is the height of the browser window. But since your html code is empty (i.e. it does not have any content), hence the offset height is 8 which is only the height of the area occupied by the `<html>` tag.

Comment: Do you know why is it 8 pixels in all browsers? Any specific reason for this?

Comment: It is due to the `margin` property in `<body>`. Set `margin:0;` style for `<body>` and the offset height will appear as 0.

Comment: Add your margin comment in original post and it will make a nice answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

the **clientHeight** property is special for the **html** element. It returns the height of the browser's client area without the horizontal scrollbar for any doctype.

If **no doctype** is specified, the **clientHeight** property of the html element contains different values in the browsers.

detail:http://help.dottoro.com/ljcadejj.php

the **offsetHeight** property is special for the **html** element.

It returns the height of the browser's client area without the horizontal scrollbar in *Internet Explorer* like the clientHeight property of the html element.

In Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, it returns the total **height of the document**.

detail: http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxqbfx.php

if you set `*{padding:0px;margin:0px;}` in css, offsetHeight will return 0 ;

http://jsfiddle.net/ufxt5Lzq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a browser issue...? This is the output from Maxthon 4.4.3.2000 console. I ran the code on this page.

[image: Maxthon 4.4.3.2000]

Comment: I tried in Google Chrome. And same thing in Internet Explorer. It's 8 pixels. You try to do it on HTML tag and please let me know what comes sir.

Comment: Of course. This is the result: document.body.parentNode.offsetHeight:2791, document.body.parentNode.clientHeight:558 And when I copied your code and opened it, it shows 8, 0. Upon reloading the clientHeight gets to 943.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by some of the other answers here, you're checking the height of a blank HTML element with no style customizations, so the `clientHeight` and `offsetHeight` are going to be the same regardless.  The content you're writing to the element are not inserted until after the document is loaded and the heights are checked, therefore producing a weird result.

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5hce6ag/3/).  I've set up a check on an element that has content and a border.  You are indeed correct that offsetHeight is larger.

If you need to do checks on an element's size, height or width, you need to do these checks **after** you've manipulated the innerHTML, or you won't get an accurate result because you're checking the **original** element size instead of the **manipulated** element size.

---

CSS:

```
#foo {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 6px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    Guess my height?<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
</div>

<div id="height"></div>
```

JS:

```
function writeLn(content) {
    document.getElementById('height').innerHTML += content + '<br />';
}

function showHeights() {
    var element = document.getElementById('foo');
    var osHeight = element.offsetHeight;
    var cHeight = element.clientHeight;

    writeLn('element.offsetHeight = ' + osHeight);
    writeLn('element.clientHeight = ' + cHeight);
}

showHeights();
```

Comment: Right. It works fine with other tags. But on `HTML` tag, it doesn't work as expected. I tried to do that thing in my code and still the `offsetHeight` is smaller. It has increased by 36 pixels because of 2 lines. That's it. But thanks because your answer cleared a different confusion I had about the content stuff. And as Cattla mentioned, these properties are special for `HTML` tag. So that's why it is smaller than `clientHeight`. :)